# how to make sidebar NOT equal to content in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, height, sidebar

I want the WordPress sidebars to have a specific height, NOT equal to the content to the post/page. Just 400px, for example. I'm working with atahualpa.
Which code in which PHP do I have to hack?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you are going to want to edit a relevant CSS file--nothing more.

Figure out which selector is appropriate for the container you want to limit and add the attributes:

```
height: 400px;
overflow: hidden;
```

Or `overflow: auto;` If you want scrollbars to appear.

Answer (score 0):

No php, do it in your theme's css file.